# Access network share with PHP5.2 + IIS7.5

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I'm using php 5.2 with IIS7.5.

I have a network share on a NAS that is username and password protected. I cannot disable or change authentication info on the NAS. I need to be able to access that network share via php.

I've done the following:

Created new user in windows whose username and password matches those on the NAS.
Created IIS application pool that uses this same auth info.
Created a web.config file inside of the php app directory with an impersonation turned on, using the same auth info.

identity impersonate="true" password="ThePass" userName="TheUser" />

Turned on ASP.NET impersonation in the application authentication in IIS.

None of this seemed to work with this simple line of code in php:

$dir = opendir("\\someservername\somesharename");
Warning: opendir(\someservername\somesharename) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No error in C:\websites\site\forum\testing.php on line 7

So, I decided to test the configuration with ASP.NET.

string[] diretories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("\\someservername\somesharename");
The asp.net test worked perfectly.

Going further down the rabbit hole, I ran phpinfo() and checked the username info in it. Down in the "Environment" section of phpinfo, I found the "USERNAME" item. Its value was "TheUser," as was what I expected.

Everything points to the system being configured correctly until I tried:

echo get_current_user();
Which returned, "IUSR." That surely isn't what I expected.

So, how in the world do I get php + IIS7.5 to read from a foreign network share?

**Update:**

Thanks to a few of the answers, I've added

```
$result = shell_exec("net use o: \\\\pathToServer\\27301  /persistent:yes 2>&1");
```

Which returns a success.  I'm still getting the error on opendir.  I tried another test and used is_dir.  This returned false on my newly created mapped drive.

```
var_dump(is_dir("o:\\"));

// Prints: bool(false)
```

**UPDATE**

I ran the script from the command line when logged in as the user that created.  The scripts executes correctly.  Could this take us back to get_current_user() which returns IUSR?  I tryied getmypid() which returned a process ID.  I cross referred that process id with the task manager and found that it was for php-cgi.exe, running under the custom user account that I made.

Comment: Have you seen [this note](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#89091) (related to mounting/accessing) and [this note](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php#75059) related to the owner of the process of the script (not the owner of the script)?

Comment: The first one doesn't apply here, they were using Apache, not IIS.

Comment: When you map a network drive, it is scoped to the user that mapped it.  You are still just accessing it via the UNC path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a test by mapping it like

```
$command = "net use $drive \"\\\\$ip\\$share\" $smb_password /user:$domain\\$smb_username";
$result = shell_exec($command);
```

on opendir you need to have \\\\$server_name\\$share try with 4 '\' and if mapping like that works and 4 '\' is failing on opendir. You may have credentials not matching.

If you map it this way new user you created in windows whose username and password matches those on the NAS will have rights on mapped drive that way you do not need to worry about the scope.

Comment: Mapping the drive worked.  But open_dir still fails.  See update in the original question.

Comment: What are your open_basedir restrictions you may want to check those since is_dir is returning false on a mapped drive.

Comment: From phpinfo: open_basedir no value no value

Comment: I've updated the post.  I ran the script from the command line as the special user, and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to access a network share in PHP is to "mount" it. Try to connect your share as a network drive.

Btw. your command is wrong
    $dir = opendir("\\someservername\somesharename");
You have to use 4 "\" because it's the escape character
    $dir = opendir("\\\\someservername\somesharename");

NOTE: [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/function.get-current-user.php) returns the owner of the process on IIS

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on a similar system. Solved this by going to web site > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication > Change IUSR to whatever your username is or use Application Pool user if correctly configured.